# application doesn't show in taskbar with application.run(FRM). Tried multiple things

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, taskbar

Running frameworks 4.0 (VB.net)

The property ShowInTaskbar is set to True.

Here the code to run the main window.

```
 Dim frm As New frmMain
 frm.ShowInTaskbar = True
 Application.Run(frm)
```

Here all the code from the frmMain

```
  Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Application.DoEvents()
        Me.Focus()
        Me.Activate()

        PeutExecuterSynchronisationAutomatique = True
        'placer le bouton d'aide en ligne 
        btnAideToolTip.Location = New Point((btnPreference.Location.X - btnAideToolTip.Width) - 5, btnAideToolTip.Location.Y)
        btnAideToolTip.Visible = True



        Label5.Text = "version(x)"

    Catch ex As Exception
        HandleException(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here all the code from the inherits form

```
Public Overridable Sub FormBase_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try


        If Not designmode AndAlso Not Application.ExecutablePath.ToLower().IndexOf("devenv.exe") > -1 Then
            If EasyDealINI.FichierINIEasyDealTailleDefaut = False Then

                Me.Height = CInt(Me.Height * Ratio)
                Me.Width = CInt(Me.Width * Ratio)
                Me.Font = New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, (Me.Font.Size * Ratio) - (DIMINUEUR_RATIO_POLICE * Ratio), Me.Font.Style)


                Me.CenterToScreen()

                UC_MenuBottom.AjusterControles()
                UC_MenuBottom.AppliquerTypeBouton()
            End If
        End If


        If Not DesignMode Then
            'Sert à ce qu'EasyDeal en plein écran n'ait pas l'air d'un Transformer qui se déplie.
            'Me.Visible = False --> Suspend le layout dans FormBaseDetailCalcul (voir AjusterControls) - Philippe 2008/06/04

            If Not FormBase.DossierImagesPath Is Nothing Then
                Dim strNomFichier As String = FormBase.DossierImagesPath & "Icone.ico"  'Le signe chinois
                'Dim strNomFichier As String = FormBase.DossierImagesPath & "Logo.ico"   'La terre
                Dim Fichier As New FileInfo(strNomFichier)
                If Fichier.Exists Then
                    Me.Icon = New Icon(strNomFichier)
                End If
            End If
        End If

        Me.MaximizeBox = False
        Me.MinimizeBox = True
        DesactiverCloseBouton()

        'Pour permettre que sur le ENTER la navigation se fasse comme en Access
        '(Agir comme un (TAB)... Voir évenement FormBase_KeyUp
        Me.KeyPreview = True
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = True
        Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen

        Me.AppliquerCouleurs(Me)

        'on met Easydeal comme texte de fenêtre 
        Me.Text = DEFAULT_WINDOW_TEXT
        Me.Focus()
        Me.Activate()

    Catch ex As Exception
        HandleException(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

but this doesn't help, even if i click on the form the app doesn't appear on the task bar.

However, what is really weird is if i put a breakpoint or if i first click on the taskbar and then click again on the form  the  program will appear on the taskbar.

An alt-tab make the program appear in the task bar too.

Thanks!

Comment: Paste more code please. The form load events at least

Comment: here it is... there is not much there though

Comment: does the application has a Title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I only have C# Examples but the same logic applies!

I have seen this issue in some cases where form Re-Sizing or Positioning is done in the Form_Load Method. Any manoeuvre like this:

```
// Set Size and location of items...
this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1012, 665);
this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1012, 665);
this.MaximizeBox = false;
```

or anything like this:

```
// Centre the main form to centre screen...
this.Location = new Point((Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size.Width / 2) - (this.Size.Width / 2), (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size.Height / 2) - (this.Size.Height / 2));
```

If you need to do any of this, make sure is done in the right place. I prefer mine in the:

```
Form1()
```

method just after the:

```
// Initialize Components...
InitializeComponent();
```

Method. This will ensure your Forms Icon will appear and solve your problem.

Comment: When you say Form's 'icon', do you mean the standard program tab to switch to that window?

Comment: The Windows Forms Application Icon, the one that would normally sit in the Taskbar when running.

Comment: In my case, setting the Opacity property in the Load event caused this issue

Answer (score 2):

What is the window's FormBorderStyle?  If it's FixedToolWindow, it wont show in the taskbar

Comment: fixed dialog or fixed single

Comment: you can reach the same effect by setting FormBorderStyle to `FixedSingle` and setting `MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` to false

Answer (score 0):

Toggle ShowInTaskbar in my form load event with these two lines:

It works only if the window is not a modal one. Which is kind of good for now.

```
This.ShowInTaskbar = False;
This.ShowInTaskbar = True;
```

However, if i set on a modal window showmeintaskbar to false  the form close itself

here is the callstack :

```
>   EasyDeal.exe!EasyDeal.Windows.UI.FrmMenuSuivi.FrmMenuSuivi_FormClosing(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e) Line 382 Basic
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosing(System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e) + 0x85 bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.CheckCloseDialog(bool closingOnly) + 0x8d bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FContinueMessageLoop(int reason, int pvLoopData, System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.MSG[] msgPeeked) + 0x148 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) + 0x1e9 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x16c bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x61 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(System.Windows.Forms.Form form) + 0x33 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window owner) + 0x38f bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog() + 0x7 bytes 
EasyDeal.exe!EasyDeal.Windows.UI.EasyDealCommon.ShowEasyDealForm(EasyDeal.Windows.UI.FormBase formToShow, EasyDeal.Windows.UI.FormBase formSender, Boolean closeFormSender, Boolean forceDialog) Line 2787 + 0xc bytes  Basic
```